# JULIA include statement error: applicable method may be too new

Tags: julia

I want to import a function present in a julia file somewhere during runtime
just like in python we have `importlib.import_module` to import module is there something present in julia

I'm new to julia and I'm not sure how to do that.
I have to import a function `main` from another julia file and want to run it but I have to also check a condition before that if the condition is true then I want to import the function.

**EDIT**

I have a file

main.jl

```
function myMain()
  s1 = "Hello"
  s2 = "World!"
  include("functions/hello.jl")
  say(s1, s2)
end

myMain()
```

hello.jl

```
function say(s1, s2)
  print(s1, s2)
end
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching say(::String, ::String)
The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 32378, while current world is 32379.
Closest candidates are:
  say(::Any, ::Any) at ~/Desktop/julia_including/functions/hello.jl:1 (method too new to be called from this world context.)
Stacktrace:
 [1] myMain()
   @ Main ~/Desktop/julia_including/main.jl:5
 [2] top-level scope
   @ ~/Desktop/julia_including/main.jl:8
in expression starting at /home/shivansh/Desktop/julia_including/main.jl:8
```

It works fine when I don't use include inside the myMain() function in main.jl

Comment: Is your condition really only given at runtime? The usual case for conditional imports can be solved by `@static if`, but that requires that the condition can be evaluated at macro expansion time. OTOH, what are the exact reasons to import at runtime? Can't you just import and _use_ conditioally? Have you checked whether Requires.jl can solve you use case?

Comment: while I agree with @przemyslaw-szufel answer, based on the error you got, it seems you have two different functions:
1- say(::Any,::Any)
2- say(::String,::String)

In that case you should use multiple dispatch, julia will use the correct function based on the type of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Julia contrary to Python is a compiled language.
Hence for maximum performance all functions should be known at the compilation time so efficient assembly code can be generated.

Hence generally you want to avoid syntax like the one you are proposing and have the `inlude` outside of the function.

However, if you really know what you are doing, why you are doing this and need such functionality then comes the world of [Julia metaprogramming](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/).

The code is the following:

```
function myMain()
   s1 = "Hello"
   s2 = "World!"
   include("say.jl")
   Base.invokelatest(say, s1, s2)
end
```

Now you can do:

```
julia> myMain()
HelloWorld!
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it just sounds like you wanna do this

```
if some_condition
    include("/path/to/some/file/that/you/need.jl")
else
    include("/path/to/some/OTHER/file/that/you/need.jl")
end
```

EDIT

I think though, after seeing the error that you added, what you wanna do is define your function multiple times instead, and with different argument types:

```
function say(x::Any, y::Any)
    println("Default")
end


function say(x::String, y::Any)
    println("String in arg1: $x")
end

function say(x::Any, y::String)
    println("String in arg2: $y")
end

function say(x::String, y::String)
    println("String in args 1 and 2: $x $y")
end
```

That way using say differs based on the datatype of the arguments:

```
julia> say("Foo", "Bar")
String in args 1 and 2: Foo Bar

julia> say("Foo", 2)
String in arg1: Foo

julia> say(0, "Bar")
String in arg2: Bar
```

and if you have two different functions that act on 2 strings you can do this instead:

```
struct MySayFunctionType{Symbol}
end

function say(x::String, y::String, ::MySayFunctionType{:Type1})
    println("Type1 function is being called: $x $y")
end

function say(x::String, y::String, ::MySayFunctionType{:Type2})
    println("Type2 function is being called: $x $y")
end
```

and then use these like this

```
if condition
    say("Foo", "Bar", MySayFunctionType{Symbol("Type1")}() )
else
    say("Foo", "Bar", MySayFunctionType{Symbol("Type2")}() )
end
```

and if you want a default version of this function to be called -- say Type2 -- you can just add a default value for the third argument like this:

```
function say(x::String, y::String, z::MySayFunctionType{:Type2}=MySayFunctionType{Symbol("Type2")}())
   println("Type2 function is being called: $x $y")
end
```

The reason this works is because "MySayFunctionType{:Type1}" is considered to be a different type than "MySayFunctionType{:Type2}" so multiple dispatch would consider that as well.

Comment: Can you please check the updated question I'm using it inside myMain function and it is showing the following error:
```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching say(::String, ::String)
The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 32378, while current world is 32379.
Closest candidates are:
  say(::Any, ::Any) at ~/Desktop/julia_including/functions/hello.jl:1 (method too new to be called from this world context.)
Stacktrace:
 [1] myMain()
   @ Main ~/Desktop/julia_including/main.jl:5
 [2] top-level scope
```
using include outside the scope of function works.